# Can you literally digitally split a display?

Tags: video, split-view

It's great that Apple has multiple desktops and you can have split screen with two full screen apps (although that could be done before with third party apps..). But I'm looking for something that allows me to split the screen itself in two desktops. This would allow two "full screen" windows on a single monitor.

I've got at least two use cases for this:

1. You want to have a video set to full screen, while also being able to have multiple other windows next to it. (If you'd go split screen, you can only have 2, i.e. Safari → Youtube + Pages)
2. You want to work with multiple windows and persistently have a set of windows unaffected (i.e. the left half of the monitor).

It would be great to literally digitally split the screen, but I have yet to discover the one that would allow that..

Comment: Guess not... :(